# Convergent Subsequences in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

In $C[0,1]$, consider the subset $E=\{ f \in C^1[0,1] \  : \ |f(0)| \leq 1, |f'(x)| \leq 1\}$

Show that every sequence in $E$ has a subsequence that converges in $C[0,1]$.

This is what I think if $E$ is closed then every sequence in E converges uniformly and is Cauchy. But $C[0,1]$ is complete so there is a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Not necessarily I can converge in $C[0,1]$ but not in $E$

Comment: Hint: Ascoli-Arzelà

Comment: @neuguy Note that $E$ is not closed in $C[0,1]$. It is however _relatively compact_.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oops. A bit careless there, yes.

Comment: Warning! Even if $C[0,1]$ is complete there is no need for its subsets to be *relatively compact* (a subset of a metric space is relatively compact when every sequence of its elements has a subsequence that converges somewhere). To wit, try analyzing the set $F=\{f\in C[0,1]\ :\ |f(0)|\le 1\}$. What can you say of the sequence $f_n(x)=1+nx$? This shows that the requirement on $f'$ that you have here is essential and cannot be removed.

Comment: So uniform boundness of derivatives implies the mean value theorem.  That is $\forall x,y$ $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq K$ $|x-y|$ where $K$ is the sup of derivatives of functins in sequence independent of $n$. So let $\delta= \varepsilon / K$ To verify  equicontinous sequences in $E$. This proves proves that sequences in $E$ has a sub sequence that converges uniformly on $C[0,1]$ @GiuseppeNegro